# how to declare class template in header file (due of circular dependencies)

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency

Having

Bar.h

```
template<class T>
class Bar<T> {
//...
}
```

Foo.h

```
template<T>
class Bar<T>;
//#include "Bar.h" removed due of circular dependencies, I include it in .cpp file

template<class T>
class Foo {
...
private:
    Bar<T> *_bar;
}
```

As you can see, I need to include bar.h but I can't do it on my project for circual dependencies reasons..

So as I usually do, I just write definition in .h and implementation in .cpp
But I have some issues with this example, because I don't know the syntax for class with template..

Is there any syntax for this?
I'm getting the following compiler error with the current example:

`Bar is not a class template`

Comment: Class templates need to be fully present, unfortunately. Also prepare an SSCCE.

Comment: i have edited my question*

Comment: ok so i have to re-design my app ><

Comment: my both circular class dependencies are using template so I can't changes the class that uses the definition + include in .cpp :/

Comment: You're defining your template incorrectly and you're forward declaring it incorrectly as well. Try `template<typename T> class Bar {};` and `template<typename T> class Bar`; as a definition and forward declaration respectively. P.S definition of a template must be present in every translation unit.

Comment: thanks a lot, i added a too much <T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declaration syntax is

```
template<T> class Bar;
```

So your code becomes:

Foo.h

```
template<T> class Bar;

template<class T>
class Foo {
...
private:
    Bar<T> *_bar;
};

#include "Foo.inl"
```

Foo.inl

```
#include "bar.h"

// Foo implementation ...
```

Bar.h

```
template<class T>
class Bar<T> {
//...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't have a circular dependency. `Bar` doesn't depend on `Foo` in any way. You can do define the templates in the following order:

```
template<class T> class Bar {};

template<class T>
class Foo {
private:
    Bar<T> *_bar;
};
```

If you wish to separate the definitions into two files, you can achieve the above ordering like this:

```
// bar:
template<class T>
class Bar {};

// foo:
#include "bar"

template<class T>
class Foo {
private:
    Bar<T> *_bar;
};
```